# Triggering add feature with geometry to open attribute feature window using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

Having a geometry, how can I trigger the add feature which opens the `Feature Attributes` window?

The user does it by clicking the `Add Point Feature` or `Add Line Feature` icon of the `Digitizing Toolbar`. I want to do in PyQGIS but I don't want the user to draw because I have the geometry.

Comment: Basically, you want to add a feature ? Look at PyQGIS 101 : https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/

Comment: No, not really. I want the user to enter the feature values.

Answer (score 4):

You can open the feature form for a particular feature like so:

```py
# change this to a reference to your layer
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

# change to a valid attribute field and value of the feature for which you want the form open
field = 'fid'
value = 914332

# use a featureRequest to find matching features (in this case only 1)
req = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(f' "{field}" = {value} ')  # for a string value enclose in single quotes f' "{field}" = \'{value}\' '
feats = list(lyr.getFeatures(req))

# get (only) feature from list
f = feats[0]

# open the feature form of the specified feature
iface.openFeatureForm(lyr, f, False)  # False means that changes made will be applied to the layer and not just the feature.

# if you want the feature attributes to be editable, toggle editing on for layer
if not lyr.isEditable():
    lyr.startEditing()
```

[image]

Comment: But it has two drawbacks:
1. "Suppress attribute form pop-up after feature creation" is ignored.
2. "Evaluate default values on provider side" is ignored or I better say, the fields don't get their default values.
So, I think the best solution is to find a way to implement what that tool does without the user drawing (geometry is given) (like in the question).

Comment: I fail to understand why you need to add a feature if the feature already exists and you don't want a new one added. Perhaps adding what you have already tried would help steer people towards a solution that fits your specifics needs (as per the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) )

Comment: And I fail to understand what you mean by "why you need to add a feature if the feature already exists and you don't want a new one added". This is not true.